# DocuSign API : Multiple Signers, complete Envelope when anyone signer signs the document

Tags: docusignapi

using DocuSign API, when a document is send to multiple signers, is there any way to complete the envelope when anyone of the signer signs the document. Eg: Document abc.txt sent to Recipient 1 and Recipient 2. if any one of the Recipient 1 or Recipient 2 signs the document, the envelope status should be set to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the specifics of your scenario, [Signing Groups](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-sending-with-signing-groups) may enable you to achieve your goal (i.e., send to a group of people, and consider the envelope 'complete' once one of those people completes/submits the Envelope).

Answer (score 0):

There is no optional signer in DocuSign. For the envelope to reach a completed status, all recipients marked as a signer, will have to finish the signing process

DocuSign supports other types of recipients. Read the [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/) and see if the other recipient types fit your usecase.